# Plant ID help please

Tags: identification

Got 3 of this plant and all of them are starting to dry out, so I pulled them off the ground and transferred them to pots to see if it's a soil issue. Also, not sure if they need partial-shade as I have them out in full sunlight.

[image: Unknown plant]

#### EDITS:

Photo of the leaves, they are shiny and narrower than most of the Jasmine I found on Google.

[image]

Scale of leaves and flowers.

[image]

This one probably won't survive the repotting :( we'll see.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is Jasmine, the flowerbuds are all wrong for Jasmine.Might be a STephanotis, S.floribunda possibly, but it doesn't  look healthy, the leaves are patchy yellow/green rather than properly green. What part of the world are you in and are you saying you planted them in the  ground and then removed them into pots because they started to look like this? Were the leaves originally dark green?

Comment: @Bamboo Southeast Asia and yes, you're correct I planted them straight to the ground when I got them and then just recently moved them 3 days ago into pots with better soil due to them drying out. There were 4 originally, one really dried out starting from the bottom up. Will check S.floribunda.

Comment: @Bamboo not S.floribunda I'm afraid, too small I've attached a photo to scale.

Comment: @Bamboo: "S." doesn't mean much. Especially for google. Before to use the abbreviation, you should write the full name of genus.

Comment: Over-fertilized? Did they improve in last 3 days? Maybe just too much sun (you say you moved recently), plants need some time to get used on new positions. On shops often plants have much more shadow.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Bamboo did write the full name in the comment: Stephanotis.

Comment: ooops. right. My eyes read it, but interpreter S as abbreviation and the rest (because upper case), as a species group.

Comment: I agree with Bamboo, the only thing in common with jasmine is the flowers have 5 petals. The details of the flower don't look right, and the leaves are completely different.

Comment: @budji - Stephanotis gets up to 10 feet, so the size doesn't rule it out,but it is also a climbing plant, and I'm not seeing anything that looks like it might twine in your image, so maybe not S. floribunda for that reason, though hard to say as its in such poor condition now -.. but it isn't Jasmine.  If it is some variety of Stephanotis, they need shade from hot sun, so a partial shade position out of midday sun, and high humidity. What soil have you used in the pots? Have you given them any fertilizer at all and if so what?

Comment: No improvement yet, but will see after a week and will move them somewhere with a bit of shade. Only using garden soil mixed in with compost and no fertilizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plant identified as *Tabernaemontana pandacaqui*

Answer (score 0):

They look fine and healthy to me. Not exactly sure what it is that's making you think it's drying out. Anyway, it appears to be a jasmine plant. Though they do prefer full sun, however in hotter regions it may actually benefit more in partial shade. Leaf fall or wilting could be sign of environmental stress as the plant has been shifted to a new location and would need a little time to settle in into its new surroundings.

Comment: Thanks, I hope it is jasmine! That's the top part of the plant which has more leaves so ID is easier, the bottom part and other side have less leaves, and two of the plants have already lost 80% of their leaves.

Comment: Well obviously you've taken the liberty to post better photos which showcases the leaf loss around the lower branches which wasn't evident as to before in the older photos. I still believe this to be a jasmine plant even though a few folks here are of a different opinion and i still stand by my comment on a change of location as the primary cause of leaf loss. Nurseries usually grow plants undercover and so require a graduate change to direct sunlight conditions adding a few hours by the day. I've bought citrus trees who exhibited the same problem with the leaves taking on a puffy apperance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a lot like a Ceylon Jasmin plant. They are commonly found in southeast Asian  and Indian gardens as they are  very easy to grow and flower year round. You can refer to the link to see if it's the same plant 
https://florafaunaweb.nparks.gov.sg/Special-Pages/plant-detail.aspx?id=2488